# Set properties of a class only through constructor

Tags: c#, properties, constructor, set

I am trying to make the properties of class which can only be set through the constructor of the same class.

Comment: Hi, the question is a bit vague, you didn't mention which programming language you're talking about and the chosen tags are poor. Can you please edit and clarify/elaborate more?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make the properties have readonly backing fields:

```
public class Thing
{
   private readonly string _value;

   public Thing(string value)
   {
      _value = value;
   }

   public string Value { get { return _value; } }
}
```

Comment: Hey David thanks for quick reply you think this makes the properties of class only set by the constructor

Comment: Yes it does.  If you're using C#, please update your tags on your original post to be more clear.  This answer is assuming you're using C#.  If you're not, again, please add a tag with the programming language you're using, so that people can understand the question more clearly.

Answer (score 63):

[This page from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383979(v=vs.140).aspx) describes how to achieve setting a property only from the constructor.

> You can make an immutable property in two ways. You can declare the
>   set accessor.to be private. The property is only settable within the
>   type, but it is immutable to consumers. You can instead declare only
>   the get accessor, which makes the property immutable everywhere except
>   in the type’s constructor.

In C# 6.0 included with Visual Studio 2015, there has been a change that allows setting of get only properties from the constructor.  And only from the constructor.

The code could therefore be simplified to just a get only property:

```
public class Thing
{
   public Thing(string value)
   {
      Value = value;
   }

   public string Value { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

With C# 9 it introduces 'init' keyword which is a variation of 'set', which is the best way to do this.

> The one big limitation today is that the properties have to be mutable
>   for object initializers to work: They function by first calling the
>   object’s constructor (the default, parameterless one in this case) and
>   then assigning to the property setters.
>
> Init-only properties fix that! They introduce an init accessor that is
>   a variant of the set accessor which can only be called during object
>   initialization:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

Ref: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/

Comment: This ref is out of date. Now that C# 9.0 has been released, an updated version can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/).

Answer (score 10):

As of c# 6.0 you now can have get only properties that can be set in the constructor (even though there is no set defined in the property itself. See [Property with private setter versus get-only-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928978/property-with-private-setter-versus-get-only-property)