# Property with private setter versus get-only-property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, c#-6.0

C# 6.0 introduces the ability to define get-only properties:

```
public ICommand AddCommand { get; }
```

Now when defining another property like the following, ReSharper suggests *Auto-property can be made get-only*:

```
private List<Screenshot> Screenshots { get; set; }
```

Futhermore, ReSharper doesn't say a thing when defining private getters:

```
public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; }
```

What's the difference between a public get-only property (such as the first `AddCommand`), a private get-only property (such as the `Screenshots` property) and the public private setter property (such as the second `AddCommand`)?

My WPF application doesn't seem to care whether its public property (UICommand) contains a private setter or no setter at all, but surely there must be a difference?

Comment: Get-only properties are kind of like `readonly` fields, they can be set in the object construction/initialization but not later. The private setter doesn't guarantee that other methods can't modify its value after construction.

Comment: What's "new" in your first property (`AddCommand`)?

Comment: @Amit: The `set` accessor is missing.

Comment: @RonBeyer So in case of WPF MVVM, when the commands are created in the ViewModel's constructor, it would be better to use get-only properties?

Comment: It would be one way of doing it, if you wanted to say that the `ICommand` doesn't change after its set. If its better or not is a matter of opinion but if it doesn't change, and you are using C#6, it can make things easier to understand and give compile errors if you try to reassign it on accident.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this specific case of binding commands, it doesn't really matter.

In other cases, i.e. having a class that gets a service injected via constructor and you want to expose it (for whatever reason), it is important to use a read-only properties.

For example:

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    public INavigationService NavigationService { get; }

    public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) 
    {
        if(navigationService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(navigationServie);

        NavigationService = navigationService;
    }
}
```

When using this, you guarantee this class invariants and it is assuring that `NavigationService` will never be `null`, hence you don't need to do null checks against `NavigationService` before using it. Once it leaves the constructor, it can't ever be changed (well, except through reflection).

On the other side if you have

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    public INavigationService NavigationService { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) 
    {
        if(navigationService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(navigationServie);

        NavigationService = navigationService;
    }
}
```

then it's possible to write code (by mistake or by a unexperienced developer) which does `NavigationService = null` and then if you don't have null-checks and access it, you will get a `NullReferenceException` and if not handled your application crashes.

Coming back to your example: In case of `ICommand`... you usually don't access Commands within your ViewModel, only assign it (usually in the constructor or when your view model's content changes, like a child viewmodel changed and you want to assign it's command to the parent viewmodel command property).

In case of a list:

If you never do `Screenshots = new List<ScreenShot>()` or `Screenshots = DisplayScreenshots()` in your code and only initialize it in the constructor, then it's indeed better to make it read only for the same reason: Then you can guarantee that `Screenshots` is never null and you won't have to write code such as

```
if(Screenshots != null) 
{
    Screenshots.Add(new Screenshot(...));
}
```

or

```
if(Screenshot == null) 
{
    Screenshots = new List<Screenshot>();
}

Screenshots.Add(new Screenshot(...));
```

again and instead always use

```
Screenshots.Add(new Screenshot(...));
```

This has a huge advantage that you need less code, your code is more readable and more maintainable, since you can't "forget" a null-check and risk a `NullReferenceException`.

Hope that cleared it up.

Answer (score 28):

Short answer:

```
public ICommand AddCommand { get; }
```

will be backed by a `readonly` field and no C# code will be able to change it beyond the execution of the constructors.

Also, the compiler will generate code to directly assign the backing filed, as there is no property accessor.

On the other hand:

```
public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; }
```

will be backed by a non-`readonly` field and can be assigned at any time by any code with access to private members.

In this case, the compiler will generate normal property setting code.

To the outside world, a private setter is as if it doesn't exist. So, it's the same as if it didn't really exist.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what your properties become after compiler did homework for you:

**1.** `public ICommand AddCommand { get; }`:

```
private readonly ICommand <AddCommand>k__BackingField;
public ICommand AddCommand {
    get { return this.<AddCommand>k__BackingField; }
}
```

**2.** `private List<Screenshot> Screenshots { get; set; }`:

```
private List<Screenshot> <Screenshots>k__BackingField;
private List<Screenshot> Screenshots { 
    get { return this.<Screenshots>k__BackingField; }
    set { this.<Screenshots>k__BackingField = value; } 
}
```

**3.** `public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; }`:

```
private ICommand <AddCommand>k__BackingField;
public ICommand AddCommand { 
    get { return this.<AddCommand>k__BackingField; } 
    private set { this.<AddCommand>k__BackingField = value; } 
}
```

**In short, public get-only property can be assigned only in constructor** (because the field is read-only) or by this new syntax:

```
public ICommand AddCommand { get; } = new MyCommand();
```

but as for any other read-only field, this code is anyway put into constructor, so there is no big difference:

```
public MyClass1()
{
    this.<AddCommand>k__BackingField = new MyCommand();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since C# 9 we also have `init` accessors. Basically it's get-only property with an exception for object initializers:

```cs
struct Point
{
    public int X { get; init; }
    public int Y { get; init; }
}
...
var p = new Point() { X = 42, Y = 13 };
```

See [MS: Init Only Setters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init).