# property type is not a valid key type in DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am getting this runtime error (Figure 1) when a WebAPI controller tries
 to get data from the repository.  The repository constructor injected a class (Figure 2) inherited from DbContext. The POCO class (Figure 3) is specified in the a DbSet points to the view (Figure 4) in the SQL Server. In the OnModelCreating() in the table key is also specified.  Why the error still occurs?  Thanks.

Figure 1:

```html
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The property 'ConsultSID' cannot be used as 
  a key property on the entity 'ConsultTB' because the 
  property type is not a valid key type. Only scalar types, 
  string and byte[] are supported key types.
```

Figure 2:

```js
namespace myOrg.Repository {
  public class MyDb: DbContext {
    public MyDb(): base("name=MyConnectionString") {}

    public virtual DbSet < ConsultTB > ConsultTBs {
      get;
      set;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
      modelBuilder.Entity < ConsultTB > ().ToTable("vConsultTB", "App");

      modelBuilder.Entity<ConsultTB>().HasKey(c => c.ConsultSID);
    }
  }
}
```

Figure 3:

```js
namespace myOrg.Data {
  public class ConsultTB {
    //[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    //[Column("ConsultSID")]
    public long ConsultSID {
      get;
    }
    public int ServiceId {
      get;
    }
    public string ServiceName {
      get;
    }
    public short Sta3n {
      get;
    }
    public string StationName {
      get;
    }
    public DateTime RequestDate {
      get;
    }
  }
}
```

Figure 4:

```js
ALTER VIEW[App].[vConsultTB]
AS
SELECT
  ISNULL(A.[ConsultSID], -1) ConsultSID, A.[Sta3n], A.[PatientSID], A.[StationName],
  A.[RequestDate],
  p.patientIEN, p.PatientName, p.PatientLastName, p.PatientFirstName, p.PatientSSN, p.StreetAddress1, p.StreetAddress2, p.StreetAddress3
FROM[schema1].[ConsultTB_Consults] A
inner join[dbserver2].[schema2].[SPatient] P
on a.patientSID = p.patientSID and a.sta3n = p.sta3n
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your properties are getter-only, which means that they can only be set by [constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38716331/861716). EF doesn't have any problems with private setters though, so you're free to use ...

```
    public long ConsultSID { get; private set; }
```

... etc.

The error message "the property type is not a valid key type" could have been a bit more to the point here.

Answer (score 2):

Properties in EF models must be writable.

You need to add `set;` accessors.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.  Just curious, this view is not updatable and will never be changed in the EF, Why do I need to make the properties in the POCO class with {get;set;}?  Thanks.

Comment: @user266909: So that EF is able to set them to the values in your DB in the first place.