# C# Get only property is set in constructor

Tags: c#, get, accessor

The whole code piece is below, as you see the Configuration is read only (get only), but why can it be set a value.

```
namespace NetCoreWP1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        .......
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ethan, this is possible of syntax changes in C# 6.0. See the answer attached [Set properties of a class only through constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357444/set-properties-of-a-class-only-through-constructor)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nico. You saved me!